# Building Expression Tree for string.Contains

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, expression-trees

I'm struggling to build an expression tree so I can dynamically do filtering on some data.

I have come up with this, but it fails at the `var lambda =` line

```
foreach (var rule in request.Where.Rules)
{
    var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), rule.Field);
    var left = Expression.Call(parameterExpression, typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower", Type.EmptyTypes));
    var right = Expression.Constant(rule.Data.ToLower());
    var method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new [] { typeof(string) });
    var call = Expression.Call(left, method, right);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(call, parameterExpression);
    query = query.Where(lambda);
}
```

The var `rule` has a Field (ex "Name") which I want to compare with the text in `rule.Data` (ex 'tom').  So if `T.Name.Contains("tom");` I want the query to include the record, otherwise, not.

The var `query` is of type `IQueryable<T>`

**EDIT**: Finally got it working with this code:

```
foreach (var rule in request.Where.Rules)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    var property = Expression.Property(parameter, rule.Field);
    var value = Expression.Constant(rule.Data);
    var type = value.Type; 
    var containsmethod = type.GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
    var call = Expression.Call(property, containsmethod, value);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(call, parameter);
    query = query.Where(lambda);
}
```

Comment: _"but it fails at the var lambda = line"_ Have you compile-time or runtime error? Can you show full exception with inner exception if any?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, updated the question with my current code, and the error

Comment: You're marking an asked and answered question from 11 months ago as a possible duplicate?  Why bother?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, but your parameter expression should be of type `T`, not `String`, you are also missing the expression that is getting the property from type `T` like name.

What you should roughly have is this

```
val -> Expression.Constant(typeof(string), rule.Field)
parameter -> Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p")
property -> Expression.Property(parameter, "PropertyName")
contains -> Expression.Call(property, containsmethod, val)
equals true -> Expression.True or equals, something like that
```

I am freehanding all of that, so it's likely somewhat different to be valid. The resulting expression should be something like this

```
p => p.Name.Contains(val)
```

Comment: rule.Field is the PropertyName, rule.Data is the value I'm trying to test if it's contained by rule.Field `"rule.Field" .Contains(rule.Data)`

Comment: I must have done something wrong, see my edit to the original post, it didn't quite work.

Comment: While I'm not 100% sure what's happening in the provider.CreateQuery, i don't think it's actualy needed. is query IQueryable<T>? If yes, then what you should be doing is `return query.Where(lambda)`

Comment: I'll try that first thing tomorrow!  Thanks.

Comment: one more quick question, how would I change this to Not Contains.

Comment: wrap the call expression in Expression.IsFalse

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create `Where` query, you must create `lambda` then call `Where` on query and pass `lambda`.
Try this:

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(call, parameter);
MethodCallExpression expression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Where",
                                    new[] { typeof(T) }, query.Expression, lambda);
query = query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(expression);
```

instead of

```
var result = Expression.IsTrue(call);
query = query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(result);
```