# Get list on basis of dropdownlist data in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controller, operators, html-select

I have two dropdownlists in my module.

In one dropdownlist, I have hardcoded all the operators like `<,>,<=,>=,==`

In second dropdownlist, I have hardcoded salary of employees like `1000,2000,3000,4000....50000`

Now if I select `<` from one list and `2000` from second list and click on submit button I should get list of employees who have salary less than 2000.

I want to do this in asp.net mvc3

How can I accomplish this task? Do I need to write a stored procedure for this?

I have created dropdownlist like:

```
viewModel.OperatorsList = new[]
{
  new SelectListItem { Value = "<", Text = "<" },
  new SelectListItem { Value = ">", Text = ">" },  
  new SelectListItem { Value = "<=", Text = "<=" },
  new SelectListItem { Value = ">=", Text = ">=" },
  new SelectListItem { Value = "==", Text = "==" }
};

viewModel.SalaryList = new[]
{
  new SelectListItem { Value = "1000", Text = "1000" },
  new SelectListItem { Value = "2000", Text = "2000" },  
  new SelectListItem { Value = "3000", Text = "3000" },

  // and so on
};
```

and I have used this to show dropdownlist in view:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Operators, Model.OperatorsList)%>
```

Comment: please show the html generated for your two dropdownLists.

Comment: and by the way, you're using EF, I guess ?

Comment: Is this satisfy ur question?an yes am using entity framework

Answer (score 6, accepted):

well, you could do something like that

assuming `viewModel` is... your `viewModel`, and you've got an entity `Employee` with a property `Salary` (`int` in this sample, it's probably a `decimal` in real world)

create a static helper class

```
public static class MyHelper
    {
        // a dictionary for your operators and corresponding ExpressionType
        public static Dictionary<string, ExpressionType> ExpressionTypeDictionary = new Dictionary<string, ExpressionType>
        {
            {"<", ExpressionType.LessThan},
            {">", ExpressionType.GreaterThan},
            {">=", ExpressionType.GreaterThanOrEqual}
            //etc
        };
        //a method to filter your queryable
        public static IQueryable<Employee> FilterSalary(this IQueryable<Employee> queryable, int salary, string operatorType)
        {
            //left part of the expression : m
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Employee), "m");
            //body is the right part of the expression : m
            Expression body = parameter;
            //m.Salary
            body = Expression.Property(body, "Salary");
            //m.Salary <= 1000 (for example)
            body = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionTypeDictionary[operatorType], body, Expression.Constant(salary));
            //m => m.Salary <=1000
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Employee, bool>>(body, new[] { parameter });
            //so it will be queryable.Where(m => m.Salary <= 1000)
            return queryable.Where(lambda);
        }
}
```

usage

```
var queryable = context.All<Employee>();//or something like that, returning an IQueryable<Employee>
queryable = queryable.FilterSalary(viewModel.Salary, viewModel.Operators);
```

Comment: Althaus:Thanks for your reply. I understood about the dictionary for operators but confused about the static class FilterSalry that you have suggested. can you please explain me something about this class?

Comment: @K2_Ketu well, the extension method `Where` takes an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` as parameter. The method is just building this expression, transforming it into a lambda, and passing it to the Where method. You might try to debug and see what's in `body` step by step, and / or google for Expression trees. I'll add some comment in my code too.

Comment: @K2_Ketu and FilterSalary is not a class, just a static extension method, like... `Where`

Comment: Althaus: Thank you so much. really it is very helpful.now I understand about this. Just little more help. can you please tell me what should be there in `typeof(YourEntity)`. bcoz as u know Employee is my entity

Comment: @K2_Ketu Well seen, it was a typo, I made a more generic version at first and forgot to correct this. Edited.

Comment: Althaus: Thank you so so much.. It is a perfect answer :-)

Comment: @Raphaël Althaus, Could you also add function 'Contains', or any user-defined string operation function? I think that maybe useful.

Comment: @LeiYang well, Contains, and other methods (so not "comparison operators") requires some other logic (you need reflection to get the methods, and use Expression.Call). You can take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614645/building-expression-tree-for-string-contains