# Building an Expression tree for Comparison Operations with value concatenated e.g ">= 1"

Tags: asp.net, linq, expression-trees

The following is a great example of how to create an Expression tree when the operator and value is passed into the method as SEPERATE parameters.

[Get list on basis of dropdownlist data in asp.net mvc3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16542968/get-list-on-basis-of-dropdownlist-data-in-asp-net-mvc3)

In my example i have several dropdownboxes where the operator and value are combined e.g. ">= 1", "< 3" etc. I could potentially split this into operator and value, passing both to the example above but was wondering if there is a simpler way to write the expression where i can just use the operator and value as one parameter, replacing MakeBinary method with an alternative.

I am relatively new to Expression trees so some guidance would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Expression trees are quite low level, and don't handle string->code. They aren't *eval*, they are *build code at runtime* (technically they are *build descriptor for code at runtime, and if you really want, compile it*.

Use a regex to split operator and value, if they are in the form `"<something"`.

```
var rx = new Regex("([<>]=?|==)(.*)");

string str = "<=1234";

var match = rx.Match(str);
string op = match.Groups[1].Value;
string val = match.Groups[2].Value;
```